# INFO: Detected dialect: W3C using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dialect, webdriver-w3c-spec

I have a web automation project that runs over a website, performs registration of new user and chooses several items. all elements are detected by findElement(By ).
Suddenly it stopped working completely and not able to find any of the elements.
My chrome is opened by no further actions are taken
the following error appears:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
22, 2020 2:57:48  org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Is there a dependency i am missing? the flow worked perfectly fine.

Comment: What is the exception? May be the site added an iframe or something changed?

Comment: can you paste the code snippet?

Comment: Your question is poor in infos. If you used findElement() in a loop i suggest to you to use use findElements() instead. If this ain't the case you must edit your question uploading a snippet of your code and better o fall the link of the webpage like @AlinStelian suggested too.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. There is no further error message and the job just times out. What could be the solution?

Answer (score 3):

### Dialect

A [dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Dialects,_flavors_and_implementations) of a programming language or a data exchange language is a (relatively small) variation or extension of the language that does not change its intrinsic nature.

---

### Enum Dialect

[`public enum Dialect`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/Dialect.html) in `org.openqa.selenium.remote` extends `java.lang.Enum<Dialect>`. This enum supports two constants:

- [`OSS`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/Dialect.html#OSS)

  ```
  public static final Dialect OSS
  ```
- [`W3C`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/Dialect.html#W3C)

  ```
  public static final Dialect W3C
  ```

[ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) earlier used the **`OSS`** dialect. But now *ChromeDriver* as a standalone server that implements the [W3C WebDriver standard](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/).

Hence now when you initiate a *Google Chrome Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session using [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you observe the `INFO`:

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

---

### Conclusion

This log message isn't an error and is an information.